# Background of listview element goes out of listview borders

Tags: android, listview, shapes

Here is a video that shows the bug: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43744171/IMG_0790.MOV (4.2мб)

Layout of the listview element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ITEM_DAY_LAYOUT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ITEM_DAY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="30 April"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="6pt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ITEM_DELETE"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ITEM_TIME"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2:28 pm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#898989"
            android:textSize="5pt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_resp_background" >

            <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
                android:id="@+id/ITEM_MESSAGE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#363636"
                android:textColorLink="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="9pt" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ITEM_MENU"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow_chat" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ITEM_IMAGE"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_ava_me"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ava_chat" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Shape layout that goes out of ListView boarders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#dff7ed" />

    <corners
        android:radius="12dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"    
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Such behavior is faced only on 1 device till now (Samsung S5 with official firmware, no root). Testing on another Samsung S5 doesn't show such behavior.

**upd1:**

Layout Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CHAT_INFO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- chat information -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/CHAT_LIST"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#e8f9f2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <!-- edit text and button send-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmmmseems like problem is not here but rather with layout where the ListView is, not with row layout

Comment: Added Layout Activity

Comment: wow so strange, are you on lollipop right? try to assign a color background to the root `LinearLayout` in your activity

Comment: Problem appears when using  target=android-19 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43744171/error_on_targret_19_HOLO_action_bar_V14.jpg I updated project to
target=android-21 (video)

Оn Samsung Galaxy S5 Android 4.4.2 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43744171/SamsungS5about.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Switching to android target 21 or even 22 did not work for me.

Turns out Samsung's Galaxy S5 has problems rendering separate corner radii but works fine if set single value for all.

i.e. replace your 
`<corners
        android:radius="12dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"

        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />`

with 
`<corners android:radius="8dp"/>`